# Undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'sym' MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to make a frequency spectrum up to 30 Hz of a Sine wave with period pi. I wrote a code but I keep getting the error : Undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'sym'

```
sint = sin(t);
Tmax = 2*pi;  %the end sample value
Ts = 0.1;   %the sampling rate
N = (Tmax/Ts)+1;  %The number of samples
Fs = 1/Ts;
t = 0:Ts:Tmax;
plot(t,sint);
f = 0:fs/(N-1):30;
z = fftshift(fft(sint));
plot(f,z);
```

Comment: `fft` is a numeric function and doesn't take symbolic arguments.  Define `t` numerically with `linspace` or some other related method, and it should be fine.

Comment: There is also a symbolic flourier transformation, but I don't see a real reason to use it here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fourier.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fft` is a **numerical** algorithm that accepts numeric inputs, not symbolic.  I suspect that you are declaring `t` before hand as symbolic.  Simply move that `t` assignment, as well as defining the sampling frequency `Fs`, sampling time `Ts` and the maximum time `Tmax` at the beginning of your code and you're good to go.   If I can suggest something, display the time domain in one graph, and the frequency domain in another.  Use `subplot` to help you do this.  I would also recommend you plot the **magnitude**, as the FFT will generally give you complex-valued coefficients.  The magnitude is what we generally look at with regards to frequency content in a signal.

One more suggestion I have is to change the way you are declaring your `f` vector.  I can't tell what the ending element is for `f` in a general sense, and it looks inconsistent with the way `t` is being defined.  I've made a change to the `f` vector to make it work.  Because you are applying `fftshift`, the beginning starts from `-Fs/2` and the end is `Fs/2`.  Therefore:

```
%// Move here
Tmax = 2*pi;  %the end sample value
Ts = 0.1;   %the sampling rate
Fs = 1/Ts;
t = 0:Ts:Tmax;

sint = sin(t);
N = (Tmax/Ts)+1;  %The number of samples
figure; subplot(2,1,1); %// Change
plot(t,sint);
%f = 0:fs/(N-1):30; %// Change here
f = linspace(-Fs/2, Fs/2, numel(t)+1);
f(end) = [];   
z = fftshift(fft(sint));
subplot(2,1,2); %// Change
plot(f,abs(z)); %// Change
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I just find the bn (the coefficient of sin Fourier series) and apply a FT via muliplying by exp^jwt, would it work?
I just applied your code, but I still get the same error...

Comment: I don't get any errors.  Mind you, I had to fix a few typos, like `fs`,`Fs`.  Try clearing your workspace by doing `clear all;` then try again.  Also, I updated my code.

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov - By definition, the Fourier Transform finds correlation between your input signal and multiples of `exp(-jwt)`.  As such, look at this definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition - Each term of the Fourier Series is defined as a combination of real (`a_n`) and imaginary `(b_n)` components.  As such, you can find your `b_n` by examining the imaginary components of the FFT decomposition.

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov - My pleasure :) If you require no more help, consider accepting my answer. Good luck!  Edited my code one more time.  It should run for you now.